# How to set a Dynamic Parallel Task Execution instead of manual call dispatch?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, refactoring, task

What is the best approach in this scenario, where in there are multiple tasks that need to be run, depending on a given parameter. See the code below:

```
void Mapping() 
{
    if(param.IsProgram1) {
        //                   spGetProgram1() is a stored procedure call
        MapProgram1(context, spGetProgram1().GetIterator());

        if(param.IsProgram2) {
           MapProgram2(context, spGetProgram2().GetIterator());
        }
    }

    if(param.IsProgram3) {
       MapProgram3(context, spGetProgram23().GetIteratior());
    }
}



 static void MapProgram1(context, IEnumerable<IDataRecord> records) {
  // map records to context
 }

 static void MapProgram2(context, IEnumerable<IDataRecord> records) {
  // map records to context
 }

 static void MapProgram3(context, IEnumerable<IDataRecord> records) {
  // map records to context
 }
```

I want to refactor this and run the tasks in parallel. My current approach is that I store the task in a dictionary and invoke it depending on the given parameter

```
 var tasks = new Dictionary<string, Task<IEnumerable<IDataRecord>>>()
 {
            { "MapProgram1", null },
            { "MapProgram2", null },
            { "MapProgram3", null },
 }

 if(param.IsProgram1) tasks["MapProgram1"].Value = Task.Run(() => spGetProgram1().GetIterator())

 ... ...


 tasks.WaitAll(tasks.Select(t => t.Value).ToArray());
```

And then fetch the result and call the corresponding mapping method like this

```
  foreach(var t in tasks.Where(t => t.Value != null))
        {
            if(t.Key == "MapProgram1")
            {
                MapProgram1(context, t.Value.Result);
            }

            if (t.Key == "MapProgram2")
            {
                MapProgram2(context, t.Value.Result);
            }

            .....
        }
```

I'm sure there's a cleaner approach on this, that I don't need to manually call the methods.

Comment: Depending on the work you might be better of looking at Parallel.For, though its hard to see what your trying to achieve

Comment: Do you want to process the recordtype in parallel i.e each type of method, or just run it all in parallel and adjust the degree of parallelism?

Comment: is it a window app or web ?

Comment: its a web service.

Comment: @Saruman I want to process all in parallel

Comment: My current approach works, but I need to eliminate the checking of key, I want the task to automagically call the MapProgram1,MapProgram2 after the result is available.

Comment: running tasks in parallel will consume your IIS worker threads..suppose your are running 3 tasks in parallel, then a web request will be consuming 4 threads (1 itself + 3 parallel tasks). If your web service will have high traffic, then you should avoid this parallelism & if not then you can go ahead with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot with `Parallel.ForEach` i.e adjust the degree of parallelism, ect

However it does depend on your work load and what you are trying to achieve, however this may give you food for thought

```
var list = new List<Stuff>();

Parallel.ForEach(list, (item) =>
{
    switch(item,ConditionType)
    {
      case ConditionType.First : DoSomethingWithItem(item); break;
      case ConditionType.Second : DoSomethingElseWithItem(item); break;
    }
});
```

**More resources**

[Parallel.ForEach Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.1)

[Msdn : How to: Write a Simple Parallel.ForEach Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I followed your example; however, in general if you want to execute tasks in parallel and conditionally choose which tasks to execute, you might do something like this...

```
    async Task Run() {
        List<Task<IResult>> tasks = new List<Task<IResult>>();
        if (someCondition) {
            tasks.Add(RunSome(someParams));
        }
        if (othercondition) {
            tasks.Add(RunOther(otherParam));
        }
        IResult[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        foreach (var result in results) {
            if (result is SomeResult someResult) {
                // Handle some result
            }
            else if (result is OtherResult otherResult) {
                // Handle other result
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task<SomeResult> RunSome(someParams) {
        // Run something
    }

    static async Task<OtherResult> RunOther(otherParams) {
        // Run other thing
    }

    interface IResult {
    }

    class SomeResult : IResult {
    }

    class OtherResult: IResult {
    }
```

You add the tasks you want to execute in parallel to a list, have each task return an instance of some result type, and then check the results after all tasks are completed.